# HashSet<custom class>.contains("String") not working

Tags: android, hashset

I have a custom class:

```
private class FeatureIndexEntry {
    public String feature_name;
    public int index;

    public FeatureIndexEntry (String feature_name) {
        this.feature_name = feature_name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        return this.feature_name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o instanceof String) {
            return ((String) o).equals(this.feature_name);
        }

        if (!(o instanceof FeatureIndexEntry)) return false;

        return ((FeatureIndexEntry) o).feature_name.equals(this.feature_name);
    }

}
```

I also have `HashSet<FeatureIndexEntry> feature_index;`, there is something already in it.

```
feature_index.add( new FeatureIndexEntry("gx") );
feature_index.add( new FeatureIndexEntry("gy") );
```

Now I want to check whether String "gx" in it, I called `feature_index.contains("gx")`, but the result is false.

After overriding method `hashCode()` and `equals()`, why it still cannot search String in it?

I checked the result `o instanceof String` in `equals`, which is always `false`, but no other types are involved.

When I create a new FeatureIndexEntry object it works fine.

```
FeatureIndexEntry a = new FeatureIndexEntry("gx");
feature_index.contains(a); // true
```

Thanks for your reading, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the first answer? It's almost correct in my situation, did I accidentally delete it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually adding **Objects of `FeatureIndexEntry`**, and seraching for `String` type object. How will this work..??

Modify your Test class as below.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<FeatureIndexEntry> feature_index = new HashSet<FeatureIndexEntry>();

        FeatureIndexEntry f1 = new FeatureIndexEntry("gx");
        FeatureIndexEntry f2 = new FeatureIndexEntry("gy");

        feature_index.add(f1);
        feature_index.add(f2);

        System.out.println(feature_index.contains(f1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I finally create a `FeatureIndexEntry` object to do this, it works fine now.

Comment: But... I just overrided its `hashCode` and `equals` method, I want to make `FeatureIndexEntry` look like `String` but no luck :(

Comment: Does Java prevent this?

Comment: *UPDATE* I tried `class FeatureIndexEntry extends Object` but no luck

Comment: @Cychih not possible, it will find for the object that you have put in to search. Hashcode will be just called to find the bucket where the objecdt lies, nothing beyond that. FOr better understanding, just debug the above test class and go deeper.